# Selenium 4.8 click request not finding element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Trying to get selenium to click confirm button

I get a :no such element: Unable to locate element:" from this command:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@value="Buy now!"] | //input[@class="orng buy-now"]'))
```

On this page

```
<div class="unibtn confirm-btn">
<span id="pblc2_ctl" class="qbutton-ctl" >
   <input type="button" name="pblc2" id="pblc2" value="Confirm" class="unibtn orng" onclick="this.disabled=true; qc.pB('BuyNowConfirmMobileForm', 'pblc2', 'QClickEvent', ''); return false;"  /></span>
</div>
```

It used to work fine, but stopped working recently.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide mode code, URL or HTML in the text form. And mention which element are you trying to locate. This is too less info for anyone to help you.

Comment: Ok after editing your question, I see the HTML you have shared. The XPATH expression you have constructed will never be able to locate the `<input>` element, as the desired element neither has @value='Buy now!' nor has @class='orng buy-now'. Now you know the root cause of your issue. Are you sure you have shared the correct HTML?